# Checking the value in a vector in R

Tags: r

> Refer the below code. `id <- 1:10`. How the warning can be avoided?

```
allFiles <- list.files(directory)

fileRange <- c(1:length(allFiles))
if(!(as.numeric(id) %in% fileRange))
{
  print("Invalid file range")
  stop()
}
```

> ```
> Warning: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> ```

Comment: Maybe you want `if( all( id %in% seq_along(fileRange) ) )`?

Comment: @Frank Yes. Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 6):

To check whether one vector lies entirely inside another, use `all`:

```
if ( all(x %in% y) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Other roads:

```
if ( all( is.element(x, y) ) )

if ( setequal( x, intersect(x, y) ) )
```